# org.dd4t.databind.DataBindFactory deprecated in DD4T 2.1.5

Tags: dd4t, upgrade

I am upgrading DD4T from 2.0.13 version to 2.1.5 and when I replaced DD4T jars I observe that my compile is failing:
[image]
If I open the `org.dd4t.databind.DataBindFactory` I see that it's deprecated:
[image]

So can someone please explain what needs to be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommended way is to autowire the databinder into your controller using Spring, using the @Autowired annotation.